Question from J. D. Lee about Quantum Numbers
There's this question in J. D. Lee: Concise Inorganic Chemistry, which I haven't understood exactly.
Which of the following may have the same set of quantum numbers?

The last electron of scandium and the last electron of iron
The unpaired electron in carbon, and the entered electron in $C^{-}$
The last electron of fluorine and the last electron of nitrogen
All of the above

My reasoning: I know option (1) is definitely correct. The last electrons of scandium and iron both lie in the $4s^2$ subshell. However, the answer key for J. D. Lee says all the statements are correct (Option 4).
If Option 2 was correct, wouldn't that be a direct violation of the Pauli Exclusion Principle? And since the last electron of nitrogen lies in the $2p_z$ orbital while the last electron of fluorine lies in the $2p_y$ orbital, wouldn't that be wrong too?
Am I missing something or is this just an error in this textbook?

Atoms are about as dumb as my cat. They don't even know which of their orbitals is $2p_y$ and which is $2p_z$, because these two look exactly the same (same energy, same everything). Hey, even we don't know the difference. There is no difference.

The word "question" in title is redundant: all posts here are questions. When citing, make sure to provide complete bibliographical info, including edition and page number(s). The symbols for orbitals and chemical elements are upright.

Thanks a lot, I get what you mean. So logically, any two electrons which have the same principal and azimuthal quantum numbers, provided that they don't pair up, could be considered to have all their quantum numbers the same?

There may be a nitpicking question what is meant by the last electron ? a) one with the highest energy b) one coming last at thought capturing electrons 1 by 1 by a naked nucleus c) one being last in orbital schema, with maximized n+l quantum numbers, coming as last to that orbital group ?

Your reasoning is plausible and the 2 electrons might be in different orbitals at an instant but the question is asking for 2 independent species. As one of the comment states, the orbitals are degenerate and they can be present in any of the three orbitals. Also the electrons keep on 'exchanging' their positions in degenerate orbitals (which provides atoms stability due to the release of exchange energy). So they may (as the question asks) have the same set of quantum numbers.

Are you referring to the revised version of JD Lee? Preparing for any competitive exam?
